# How to save two classes having one to one relationship using Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, api, rest

I've created a Spring application using Hibernate in which I've implemented one to one relationship between user and address table. Two tables are created for the same like, one for the user and another for the address. Now, I would like to implement the same, but facing hurdles. Following is my approach,

1. Created an address class along with its getters and setters.
2. Created a user class along with its getters and setters + @OneToOne mapping with address class.Like,

> ```
> @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
> @JoinColumn(name = "AddressId")
> private Address address;
> ```

3. Createed a DAO & Service class for user and address.
4. How do I call service class in my controller so that It took user and address details as my input and save the same in the database?

> ```
> @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
>   public @ResponseBody Status addUserAddress(@RequestBody User user)
>           throws Exception {
>       userServices.addUser(user);
>        // What shall I add here to save address also?
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `entityManager.persist(user)` is sufficient, since you have a `cascade=ALL` on the association: the entity manager will persist the user and cascade the persist operation on the address.

Comment: Will you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't know what to add. What don't you understand?

Comment: "Calling entityManager.persist(user) is sufficient,"... What do I need to change in above mentioned controller? Shall I add user and address details as an input json for the created API?

Comment: You need to make the method compile by returning a Status. Your method already takes a user as argument, and inside the user, you have the user's address. So the method passes the user (containing his address) to the service, which, I guess, passes it to the DAO, which just needs to persist the user. Persisting the user will also persist the user's address.

Comment: I did the same, but when I passing the JSON as an input using address parameters then it prompts 404 and when I remove address parameters and kept just user parameter then it prompts that "Column 'AddressId' cannot be null"

Comment: There's no way a difference in the JSON causes a 404. And if you want help on the exception, then edit your question and add the full stack trace of the exception, the code causing the exception, the code of the entities, and the schema of the tables. If the column is non null, you should have `optional = false` in the OneToOne annotation.

Comment: I have not created a code for the same. Getting confused like, how shall I start? How do I send JSON input which splits the details into two tables? Please help sir.